# Swift equivalent to __attribute((objc_requires_super))?

Tags: swift

Is there a Swift equivalent to

```
__attribute((objc_requires_super))
```

which gives a warning if a method doesn't call it's super method?

Basically, I want to warn (or even better, throw a compiler error) if an overridden method doesn't call its super method.

Comment: [file a bug report/feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Found this on OpenRadar: [Attribute equivalent of NS_REQUIRES_SUPER](http://openradar.appspot.com/17408107)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no Swift equivalent to `__attribute((objc_requires_super))`.

The equivalent feature, [Swift Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html), contains no such attribute.

The section of the [Swift inheritance documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-XID_296) where such a feature *would* be mentioned says only:

> When you provide a method, property, or subscript override for a subclass, it is sometimes useful to use the existing superclass implementation as part of your override.

---

Note that you **can** prevent overriding functions using `final`, so you could *effectively* accomplish what you want by providing empty overridable methods that are called by non-overridable methods:

```
class AbstractStarship {
    var tractorBeamOn = false

    final func enableTractorBeam() {
        tractorBeamOn = true

        println("tractor beam successfully enabled")

        tractorBeamDidEnable()
    }

    func tractorBeamDidEnable() {
        // Empty default implementation
    }
}

class FancyStarship : AbstractStarship {
    var enableDiscoBall = false

    override func tractorBeamDidEnable() {
        super.tractorBeamDidEnable() // this line is irrelevant

        enableDiscoBall = true
    }
}
```

Subclasses would then override the overridable methods, and it wouldn't matter whether they called `super` or not since the superclass's implementation is empty.

As [Bryan Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642626/bryan-chen) notes in the comments, this breaks down if the subclass is subclassed.

I make no claims to whether this approach is *stylistically good*, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: how about `MoreFancyStarship` that is subclass of `FancyStarship`? its `super.tractorBeamDidEnable` is no longer empty method

Comment: @BryanChen Right, it's certainly not a perfect replacement, both in terms of verbosity and the reason you mentioned. If you wanted to enforce it, `AbstractStarship` could have some runtime error if its implementation of `tractorBeamDidEnable()` isn't called before `enableTractorBeam()` returns. Of course, this is also an imperfect solution because the developer has no indication this is wrong until the code runs, unlike `objc_requires_super`.