# Is there a way to annotate a swift method as requiring a call to its superclass's implementation

Tags: swift, subclass

I have a superclass that has a basic implementation of a method (`prepareForSegue:sender:` in my case), and I want to ensure that any subclass which overrides this method calls the super's implementation.

```
class A {
    func foo() {
        // Some basic shared behavior
    }
}

class B : A {
    override func foo() {
        // I want the compiler to yell at me if I forget super.foo() here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER` in swift, or perhaps a way to mimic this behavior using protocols?

Comment: Same question here, doesn't seem like there is such a way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210646/swift-equivalent-to-attributeobjc-requires-super

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way round this which might work:

```
class A {
    private func foo() { println("A: Foo") }

    final func bar() {
        println("A: Bar")
        foo()
    }
} 

class B : A {
    override private func foo() { println("B: foo") }  
}

var a = A()  
a.bar()       // "A: Bar\nA: Foo"
println()
var b = B()
b.bar()       // "A: Bar\nB: Foo"
```

This code disallows the override of the `bar()` method, but allows for override of the `foo()` method. The trick then is that the user needs to call the `bar()` method instead of the `foo()` method, but if you make that happen, then you are ensured that the superclass method, i.e. `println("A: Bar")` is always called! :-)